# Sum of matches found in a CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have csv data that looks like:

```
17860   1 
17861   1 
17861   2 
17861   1 
17861   1 
17861   1 
17862   1 
17863   1 
17863   1 
17863   1
```

My goal is to get the output to display the sum of matches on the left column, to get a result such as:

```
17860    1
17861    6
17862    1
17863    3
```

What I'm having trouble with is how to go about storing the 5 digit number and comparing it to the rest of the data in the column and then capturing the single digit number to get the sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage a Hash (aka Dictionary in Python) data structure. Read through your file and store the first column numbers as keys and the second as values. If you find that the key is already present, then add the current value to the previous one, or add the new key itself.

```
hash = {}
for line in file:
    key, value = map(int, line.split())
    if key in hash:
        hash[key] += value
    else:
        hash[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ sum[$1] += $2 } END { for (i in sum) print i, sum[i] }' t.txt
17862 1
17863 3
17860 1
17861 6
```

Or perhaps more readable, put this in a file and `chmod +x` it and you can run it as a program:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
  sum[$1] += $2
}

END {
  for (i in sum)
    print i, sum[i]
}
```

Comment: what is this? a script?

Comment: @Nabin: this is a script in the AWK language.  The OP never mentioned Python in the question, only in the tags.

Comment: It is always a good idea to resolve an issue as quickly and safely as possible. The question did not read "My goal is to get a dict like `{ 17860: 1, 17861:   6,... }` for further processing in python put for printed output. Compare the `awk` solution with the `python` script by Vivek (which does not even print as requested). `awk` is specialized on this type of tasks and you will not have to take care on importing someting, or think about using `print` with `()` or without ;)